# Bitlocker Locked PC

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

This morning I turned off Secure Boot on my PC and then re-enabled it. Some time laterz I attempted to boot normally but Bitlocker demanded my recovery key which for one reason or another I do not have, saying "your security protocols have changed unexpectedly"

Comment: BitLocker has a security feature, when any configuration change is detected, the BItlocker recovery is required. WIthout the BitLocker recovery key there is no solution to your problem that doesn't involve a restore from backup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The chances for recovering your disk are slim.

See Microsoft's article
[Finding your BitLocker recovery key in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6).

If you are using a Microsoft account, the key may be found in there,
as described in the article.

Otherwise, if none of the other listed methods apply to your case,
the disk contents are lost and need to be returned from backup.